# Conversion of expression from Prefix to Postfix notation (Problem with precedence)

Tags: java, algorithm, homework, converting

I have been attempting to write a code that converts Prefix expressions to Postfix expressions.

So far here's what I have made (note that I am new and hence it may not be efficient!)

```
/***************************************************
 NOTE: This code fails to realise the precedence
    of parentheses and $ (exponential) expressions
****************************************************/

import java.util.Scanner;

class Stack{
    //Private Declarations
    private int top;
    private String a[] = new String [100];
    //Public Declarations
    public Stack(){
        top = -1;
        a[0] = "\0";
    }
    public void push(String x){
        if (top != 99){
            a[++top] = x;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Stack overflow");
        }
    };
    public String pop(){
        if (top == -1){
            System.out.println("\nStack empty!");
            return "\n";
        }
        else{
            return a[top--];
        }
    };
    public int ret_top(){
        return top;
    };
}


public class Prefix2Postfix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declaration
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        Stack op = new Stack ();
        Stack sym = new Stack ();
        char ch;
        int i;
        String exp, str, str1, str2, str3;

        //Taking input from the user
        System.out.println("Enter the prefix expression : ");
        exp = in.next();

        for (i=0; i<exp.length(); i++){
            ch = exp.charAt(i);
            if((ch == '+')
             ||(ch == '-')
             ||(ch == '*')
             ||(ch == '/')
             ||(ch == '$')){
                str = Character.toString(ch);
                op.push(str);
            }
            else{
                str = Character.toString(ch);
                sym.push(str);
            if (sym.ret_top() == 1){
                str1 = sym.pop();
                str2 = sym.pop();
                str3 = op.pop();
                str1 = str2.concat(str1);
                str1 = str1.concat(str3);
                sym.push(str1);
            }
            }
        }

        //Output
        str = sym.pop();
        System.out.println("After conversion to postfix" + ": " + str);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

As I have already commented in the code, my code fails to realize the precedence in the case of prefix expressions.

For example:

> Infix   : a + (b*c)
>
> Prefix  : +a*bc
>
> Postfix : abc*+ //Expected output
>
> Output I get : ab*c+

Is something wrong with the logic I am using, or is there something I need to add?
Can you please suggest some method by means of which my code can work properly?
If anybody can help I will be grateful.

NB: Our professor has advised us to write our own stack class and code. Please also note that this is kind of a homework assignment.

**Edit:** To make sure my Stack class works fine I have written this piece of code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class STACK {
    //Private Declarations
    private int top;
    private int elem[] = new int [100];
    //Public Declarations
    public STACK (){
        top = -1;
        elem[0] = 0;
    }
    public void push(int x){
        if (top != 99){
            elem[++top] = x;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Stack overflow");
        }
    };
    public int pop(){
        if (top == -1){
            System.out.println("Stack empty!");
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return elem[top--];
        }
    };
}

public class StackPushPop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        STACK s = new STACK();
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int choice, x;
        do{
            System.out.println("Menu Options :");
            System.out.println("1 -> Push an element");
            System.out.println("2 -> Pop an element");
            System.out.println("3 -> Empty complete stack");
            System.out.println("Any other input for exit");
            System.out.println("Your choice : ");
            choice = in.nextInt();
            switch(choice){
                case 1: 
                    System.out.println("\nEnter element : ");
                    x = in.nextInt();
                    s.push(x);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("\nPopping element : ");
                    x = s.pop();
                    if (x != 0){
                        System.out.println(x);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("\nEmptying stack!");
                    x = 1;
                    while (x!= 0){
                        x = s.pop();
                        if(x != 0){
                            System.out.print(x + "  ");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    choice = 0;
            }

        }while (choice != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: May be here is bug: `a[++top] = x;` You will write first value at index 1, not 0.

Comment: @k06a : Please check the code properly. In my constructor I have assigned top to -1. Hence a[++top] = x; will first increase top to 0 and then store value at a[0].

Comment: This is Java code. Why is there a C++ tag?

Comment: I am so sorry. I must have put it there by mistake. Thanks for pointing that out, I will remove it right away.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a constant that represents the size of your array. If tomorrow you want the array to be 200 elements and just change

```
private String a[] = new String [200];
```

your code will break.

However if you class looked like the following, changing the size of the stack is simple and easy.

```
class Stack{
    private static final int STACK_SIZE = 100;
    private String a[] = new String [STACK_SIZE];
    //...
    public void push(String x){
        if (top <= STACK_SIZE-1){
            a[++top] = x;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Stack overflow");
        }
    };
}
```

Also, if you accidentally increment `top` by more than one, `top != STACK_SIZE-1` can fail and cause an indexing error. Checking for less than or equal is what you want to do conceptually, so have the code actually do that.

---

```
public int ret_top(){
    return top;
};
```

The convention is to name this type of method `getTop()` (note both the name and casing).

---

You don't need to define all of you variables at the start of `main()`. Try to keep a variable as tightly scoped as you can. This will improve memory usage because instances you no longer need can be garbage collected. But more importantly, it will prevent you from accidentally using a value from a previous usage that you did not intend to use.

Additionally, names like `str2` are not good variable names. The type system tells me that the variable is a `String`, so you shouldn't need to put the type in the name. Your variable names should describe what the value is conceptually.
What makes a value popped from `op` different from a value popped from `sym`?

On more thing, you don't need to keep variable names to less than 5 characters. I can guess what `sym` and `op` stand for, but it would be better if the code just told me. You shouldn't jump to 50 character names, but actual words are generally better than abbreviations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am a beginner and am learning to code. I find your answer really useful in the long run. But it still does not answer my question and hence I can't accept it.

Comment: @iluvthee07: Code Review is designed for getting comments on code quality. Think "Is this code good? Could it be better?" For "Why doesn't this work?" StackOverflow is best.

Comment: I accept the point you brought to my notice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about Polish notation (PN) and reverse Polish notation (RPN):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Looks like you need to write some tests for your **stack** and **function** to make sure all works fine.

And IMHO it will be more clear to rewrite your `if` with `switch`:

```
switch (ch)
{
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '$':
         // ...

    default:
         // ...
}
```

Comment: My stack works fine but the fact that precedence in my Polish notation is ignored is whats bugging me.

Comment: @iluvthee07 only tests can prove yourcode works fine. Your comments can't :)

Comment: @iluvthee07 please post test, witch your code fails ..

Comment: I have given the test for which my code fails in the question, please see it.

Comment: @iluvthee07: When people talk about tests, they mean code that calls a certain function with a set of inputs and verify that the output or state change is what is expected. Try looking into unit tests. What you posted allows you to manually test `Stack`. Every time you make a change, you have to repeat the same process. Additionally, it is not testing is the parsing logic in `main()`.

Comment: @unholysampler : Can you provide me with examples or links to examples of what you just said so that I can try it out?

Comment: @iluvthee07: JUnit is a popular unit test framework. [Tutorial on JUnit](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html) Even if you don't end up using JUnit, the core concepts should carry over.